# How to use UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke with udfs in a where clause

Tags: .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I try to create a user defined function in DocumentDB to use it in a where clause but execution of the query throws a `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException` with the following message:

*Constant of type 'System.Object' is not supported.*

The following code illustrates the described behavior. Am I doing something wrong?

```
string udfName = "udfDemo";
UserDefinedFunction udfDemo = new UserDefinedFunction()
{
    Id = udfName,
    Body = @"function(a, b) {
                return true;
             }"
};

UserDefinedFunction createdUdf = documentClient.UpsertUserDefinedFunctionAsync(documentCollectionUri, udfDemo).Result;

int intParameter1 = 1;

IQueryable<MyModel> query= documentClient
    .CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(documentCollectionUri)
    .Where(order =>
        (bool)UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke(udfName, order.CancelationDetails, intParameter1));

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to repro this on a sample project that happened to be using `'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.5.0'`

The error disappeared when I replaced the reference to `intParameter1` in the `Invoke` call with `Convert.ToString(intParameter1)`.

(I don't know why I'm just getting started in this technology myself)

I then tried updating the packages to the latest available from Nuget `'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.1.9.2'` and reverted back to just using `intParameter1` and that too now works without error.

So maybe a bug that has since been fixed. Specifically [Release Notes
1.9.1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sdk-dotnet/#release-notes) states

> Fixed the ability to use parameters of different types when using user
>   defined functions in LINQ.

Comment: You are right, Martin! As Rajesh said the bug was fixed. After contacting Andrew Liu via mail and directing him to this SO post the DocumentDB team did some further investigation and fixed this bug with Microsoft Azure DocumentDB Client Library 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this bug was fixed in .NET SDK 1.9.2 after it was reported here.

Thanks!